# How to retrieve the sum of the selected category from SQLite category_column?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

My table contains these columns:

```
1 - id integer
2 - car_model text`
3 - car_value int
4 - car_color
```

Code:

```
public static final String CREATE_query = "create table car" + "(id integer primary key autoincrement,carmodel text not null,carvalue integer not null,carcolor text not null)";
```

The problem I face is how to get the total value of selected car model in a Spinner and display the value using a TextView

I use this to query the database

```
 public float getCarModelValue(SQLiteDatabase db, String selectedmodel) {


     float amount = 0;
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "select sum(carvalue) from car where carmodel = '"+ selectedmodel;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            amount = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();


    return amount;


}
```

but it fails.
Also I tried the following code

```
public float getAccountValue(SQLiteDatabase db, String selected) {

         float amount = 0;
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "select sum(carvalue) from car group by carmodel where carmodel = " + selected;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                amount = cursor.getInt(0);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();


        return amount;


    }
```

And use this code to display value

```
dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqlitedatabase = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        try {


            valueofcar = dbhelper.getCarModelValue(sqlitedatabase, model_selected);
            total_value.setText("" + valueofcar);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

any help appreciated

Comment: How does it fail? Can you post your logcat when the error happens?

Comment: @DanielK   logcat doesn't show any error

Answer (score 4):

You need to close the string delimiter:

Wrong:

```
String query = "select sum(carvalue) from car where carmodel = '"+ selectedmodel;
```

Correct:

```
String query = "select sum(carvalue) from car where carmodel = '"+ selectedmodel + "'";
```

---

Similarily, in the other method, the correct query is

```
String query = "select sum(carvalue) from car group by carmodel where carmodel = '" + selected + "'";
```

---

In both methods, you don't need this: `group by carmodel`, nor the `do ... while` loop - since you are only retrieving a single value.

Comment: It's the only way it will work. Because carmodel is a TEXT field.

Comment: I'm talking of the `getCarModelValue()` method. The `getAccountValue()` method is very similar.

Comment: what value you are getting in amount?

Comment: @VikashKumarVerma no value displayed

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to store result in a new column and read from it

and get the result

```
    public float getCarModelValue(SQLiteDatabase db, String selectedmodel) {

         float amount = 0;
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select sum(carvalue) from car as totalcar where carmodel = '"+ selectedmodel + "'";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String query = "select totalcar from car";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
cursor=cursor.moveToFirst();
        amount=cursor.getInt(getColumnIndex(totalcar));    
        db.close();
        return amount;
    }
```

Comment: Kumar  how can i implement these methods ??????!!!!   please code example if available